# C++ Non-static member functions overhead

Tags: c++, class, optimization, overhead

I would like to know that, if we have the following class:

```
class MyClass  
{
public:
  MyClass(...)  
  type nonstatic_func1(...);
  type nonstatic_func2(...);
  ...
  type nonstatic_func10(...);
private:
  type var1;
  type var2;
  ...
  type var10;
};
```

Will each instance of `MyClass` have its own set of ten functions (i.e. for each instance, will a "version" of each of the ten functions be created)? How much will having, say, 20 functions in a class definition impact performance, as opposed to having, say, 2 functions (non-static), especially regarding instantiation, but also in working with these instances? How much will the amount of variables affect the performance? (see the next paragraph, the `vector` part)

The reason I am asking is I am writing a program that is instantiating a lot of instances of a class (to illustrate, I have quite a large vector, i.e. `vector<MyClass> vec`, for example), and the program is running slower than I anticipated.

In a nutshell, I'd like to know how much overhead there is in instantiating, and working with, an instance of a class that has a lot of non-static functions/variables.

**EDIT**

One of the things I do with my large vector of class instances is sorting...this is the main thing I suspect is draining performance, since there's a lot of moving (and copying, explicitly and implicitly) elements (instances) around and between vectors. Obviously if the chunk of data that has to be moved and copied so much is quite large, it could drain performance.

Comment: `Will each instance of MyClass have its own set of ten functions` No

Comment: About the variables, how big is your vector? Can you measure which lines of code are actually slow, without guessing?

Comment: I am quite sure it's the sorting that is doing it. If I comment the sorting out, it runs as fast as I expect. I have managed to optimize the sorting to the extent where I just erase an element at each step (the amount of steps being half the size of the vector), but the erase might do a lot of operations in the background with the instances (since I am not popping from the back).

Comment: All instances of a non-template class run the exact same code.  To a member function, the only difference between instances is a different `this` pointer.

Comment: @KonradKapp Are you writing your own sorting function? Are you sure the one available in the standard lib isn´t faster? ... What algo are you using?

Comment: To elaborate further, I have to find the top `n` elements in an unsorted array that is of size `2n`. At first I sorted it using a simple insertion sort (with n = 50, which I thought was pretty small so, no big deal), but then I found a quicker way to just find the top 50 elements. Btw, yes, I am writing my own sorting algorithms, since it's an array of objects and not of values. I can get the values they are sorted on by calling a method on them, though.

Comment: `I am writing my own sorting algorithms, since it's an array of objects and not of values` So what? Use the stdlib. And about the "50"... if a vector with 50 elements (or 2*50=100) is a problem, you´re doing something very very wrong. But without seeing the code, nobody can help you there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will each instance of MyClass have its own set of ten functions

No.

> How much will having, say, 20 functions in a class definition impact performance, as opposed to having, say, 2 functions (non-static), especially regarding instantiation, but also in working with these instances?

Therefore, no.

> How much will the amount of variables affect the performance?

The major impact of having a lot of member variable is that each instance occupies a lot of memory space. The consequence of being big in size is it would spend a lot of time when it is copied. A less obvious time overhead would be in CPU caching.

But these overhead may not be the causes of your problem.

> One of the things I do with my large vector of class instances is sorting...this is the main thing I suspect is draining performance

Don't suspect. Measure. To track down where the performance goes, find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Yes, I have determined that it is the sorting...sorry I am a bit tired at the moment, did not mention it at first in my post. Btw, are there a lot of overheads in working with a class instance in general, aside from the content (i.e. member variables)?

Comment: > "Don't suspect. Measure" <-- This needs to be bolder.  Maybe <blink> and <marquee>.  Maybe just replace the whole answer with this line.  It's that important.

Comment: @KonradKapp Other than member vars, there is *nothing* in an object. Without variables, there is no overhead at all, not even nanoseconds or whatever.

Comment: @KonradKapp In general, no, unless you have virtual functions. If you are sure the problem is the sorting, consider other data structures and algorithm, and improve the program flows to minimize the need of sorting.

Comment: I have actually thought of replacing the actual objects in the vector with pointers to the objects...think those are only about 8 bytes each that will be copied/moved around, instead of all the variables and vectors in the class object. Since I am still erasing from within the vector, there are probably a lot of behind the scenes stuff going on, which might be slowing it (since all the behind the scenes action is probably copying/moving the big objects).

Comment: I don´t get what you´re doing, but a) Use proper data structures. If you need to add/delete elements very often, vector is bad. b) Use proper algoirthms. Currently it sounds like you have your own sorting algo, the one in the stdlib is better (probably). c) Learning about move semantics could help too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. Will try to use my own data structures. Btw, I am just using C++ to implement some evolutionary algorithms for optimization, which people normally use a more lightweight language like Python or Matlab for. So I am taking the hard route here, but I prefer to use C++ to sharpen my skills in it, since it's such a powerful and flexible language :)

Comment: @KonradKapp And please don´t roll your own data structures, if you own sorting algo has trouble with 50 elements. The stdlib has some data structures too. About the languages: Writing slow programs in C++ is easy ... writing programs which are only surpassed by Asm is not. Real speed optimization is hard.

Comment: @KonradKapp And even if the data structures in the Standard Library does not suit your need, there are a lot of open source libraries out there. It should be the last resort to write your own.

Comment: @deviantfan  It's not that the sorting algo takes long for one sorting, it definitely takes less than a second to sort the 50 elements (with my own sorting algo and `vector`), but the thing is, it has to do it about 100 - 200 times at least.

Comment: @KonradKapp Then, use a combination of `std::nth_element` and `std::sort` or `std::partial_sort` or something else. Raise another question about it and maybe someone will tell you more details.

Comment: @NickyC thanks, will check C++ reference for `std::nth_element`

Comment: @KonradKapp (still more about your 50 in less than one second: Look at https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/24/cpp-11-sort-benchmark/ . Around 800000 in less than one second, with the stdlib sort stuff. The used computer is not bad, but still "normal")

Comment: @deviantfan the link you sent me seems to be broken, but the "sorting" algorithm that I wrote takes about 0.02 seconds, to be more precise :). But I guess stdlib is the way to go then. (btw I think for educational purposes, it's not always such a bad idea to reinvent the wheel, if you have the time on your hands)