# Reducing non-static member function overhead

Tags: c++, performance, inlining

I have a computational physics code (finite difference) that performs operations (derivatives) on large arrays of data (solution fields and coefficient fields).
The coefficient data is stored as an array of `Model` objects with an overloaded `()` operator.
The following class is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
class Model
{
public: 
    inline double operator () (double field)
    {
        return alpha*field;
    }
private:
double alpha ;
}
```

The application would use an array of `Models`:

```
std::vector<Model> models; // array of models
std::vector<double> input;
std::vector<double> output;
...    
for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++)
{
    output[i] = models[i](input[i]);
}
```

The problem is that there is a significant overhead from using the `()` operator.

I've profiled the code as-is, and then again where I removed the `()` operator and wrote the code inline. (I am using g++ 7.3.0., running on Ubuntu 18.04). I am compiling with `-Winline` and g++ does not complain that it cannot inline the function.

I have also tried using a `static` function in place of the `()` operator, and that did not have the same overhead. Unfortunately a static function cannot access member variables. Other posts indicate that this should not be a problem ( e.g. [C++ Non-static member functions overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197183/c-non-static-member-functions-overhead)) but it certainly seems to be here.

So my question is: where is the overhead coming from with this non-static member function?

Comment: What level of optimization do you use? How big are the differences in time between this code and manually inlined one?

Comment: ... and at this level perhaps `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size` could make a difference. Edit: I have not done this many times but - avoid cache-line clashes - and it'll usuallly be faster.

Comment: Did you look at the generated code? What compiler options did you use?

Comment: I looked at the generated code using full optimizations and there is _no_ overhead for the `operator()` call, since it is inlined.  What compiler and options are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between static and non-static is the `this` pointer. The code is shared between all instances, but there is an implicit argument to the function to access the members of the class. So there is no memory overhead like the question you refer but there is a small cost in time due to passing of `this`, and the pointer dereference to access the member variable. You could check the generated assembly file to make sure it's inline.

Suggestions to speed up the execution:

- Use compiler optimizations
- Use Parallelism: C++ Threads or OpenMP are easy options here
- Change your design to use a vector of alphas and remove the class, then you could perhaps use SIMD

Comment: I'm aware of the distinction. It is unlikely that the pointer dereference is the issue. When testing the manually inlined code I added an extra dereference to see if that was the issue - no change. And regarding speed: I already used compiler optimization along with MPI, OpenMP and Cuda. Finally, changing the vector structure is not an option as that would require complete code redesign.

Comment: Depends on the pointer referencing a memory that is in the local cache or not. Accessing data outside the cache has a huge penalty. The only other micro-optimization that I am aware and could be attempted is nothrow()